# How Can I retrieve all posts shared on google+ from a specific Domain?

Tags: api, google-plus, posts

I want to retrieve domain specific posts shared on google through API. Can some body please help me that which API should be suitable for it?

Comment: What do you mean by domain specific posts? Google+ posts sharing links of a domain? Or posts shared by a Google Apps domain?

Comment: Domain specific posts mean all posts shared from a specific domain on google +  like all posts shared from http://webquestionanswers.com/ on google+

Answer (score 0):

The API providing functionality closest to what you are looking for is [activities.search](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/search). It will only return public posts, it may return posts with the domain in the post text, and it is likely to be incomplete. You will have to surround the domain with quotes like `"example.com"` and `orderBy=recent`.

[Example query](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.search?query=%2522example.com%2522&orderBy=recent&_h=1&)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will check with it and get back to you.